# How to avoid re-memory allocation to an object

Tags: c#

The Code below sets the value to an object using reflection. The issue is, it is reallocating the memory to the subfield (Name) of the main object (refObj). Instead of setting the value at the existing memory location.

```
namespace MemoryAllocation
{
    class Name
    {
        public string name;

        public Name(string n)
        {
            name = n;
        }
    }

    class PersonData
    {
        public Name PersonName;
        public int age;

        public PersonData()
        {
            age = 0;
            PersonName = new Name("");
        }
    }

    class ReflectionPractice
    {
        object localObj;
        Type type;

        public ReflectionPractice( object refObj)
        {
            localObj = refObj;
            type = refObj.GetType();
        }

        public void setValueToObject1()
        {
            FieldInfo fi1 = type.GetField("age");
            FieldInfo fi2 = type.GetField("PersonName");
            Name personName = new Name("This is first name");
            fi1.SetValue(localObj, 34);
            fi2.SetValue(localObj, personName);

        }

        public void setValueToObject2()
        {
            FieldInfo fi1 = type.GetField("age");
            FieldInfo fi2 = type.GetField("PersonName");
            Name personName = new Name("This is second name");
            fi1.SetValue(localObj, 27);
            fi2.SetValue(localObj, personName);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object refObj = new PersonData();
            Name personName;
            ReflectionPractice reflection = new ReflectionPractice(refObj);

            reflection.setValueToObject1();

            personName = (refObj as PersonData).PersonName;

            Console.WriteLine(personName.name);
            Console.WriteLine((refObj as PersonData).PersonName.name);


            reflection.setValueToObject2();

            Console.WriteLine(personName.name);
            Console.WriteLine((refObj as PersonData).PersonName.name);
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output should be

```
This is first name
This is first name
This is second name
This is second name
```

but it is like

```
This is first name
This is first name
This is first name
This is second name
```

If inside the ReflectionPractice class, I move the Name object outside the "setValueToObject" method and allocate memory once then the out is correct. But in my problem scenario, I have to allocate memory to Name every time I call "setValueToObject" method. Any solution suggestions will be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: sorry, the tag was added by mistake. :-)

Comment: Good time to use your debugger to see the actual values of the internal fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using C# 7.0 it is quite an easy fix. First to why this happens, if it isn't clear. When you fetch `personName` the first time, it fetches an address to the object `PersonName`, which is the same as the address in the `refObj`. Once you call `setValueToObject2`, the Object itself is not changed, but a new one is generated at a new address. The address is then assigned to the `refObj.PersonName`, but your local reference does not know any of this and still points to the initial object, which is the correct and expected behaviour.

To change this and explicitly follow changes to the source at `refObj.PersonName`, you'll need to declare the local variable `personName` as a `ref`-Variable. `personName` will no longer point to the Object itself, but to `refObj.PersonName` and whatever is behind that Variable, so it will also Update when you change that Variable.

A working example would look like this:

```
object refObj = new PersonData();
ReflectionPractice reflection = new ReflectionPractice(refObj);

reflection.setValueToObject1();

ref Name personName =  ref (refObj as PersonData).PersonName;

Console.WriteLine(personName.name);
Console.WriteLine((refObj as PersonData).PersonName.name);


reflection.setValueToObject2();

Console.WriteLine(personName.name);
Console.WriteLine((refObj as PersonData).PersonName.name);
```

**Some more in-depth explanation:**
When you assign an Object to a Variable, you indeed assign a reference to the Object not the Value of the Object itself. This reference is a Number, wich tells us where to look for the Data of the Object. So if I say `reflection.setValueToObject1()`, a new Object gets generated at Address `1234` for example. This number is what the Variable `refObj.PersonName` will contain, you'll never see that number though. When you assign a Variable with a reference to that new object, the only thing done is to copy that number into the new Variable. So after you say `personName = refObj.PersonName`, `personName` now also holds the Address `1234` and thus points to the same Object as `refObj.PersonName`.

As we can see, if we set `refObj.PersonName.Name = "Test"` the programm will first look into `refObj.PersonName` and take that Address. It then goes to said Address and changes the Value of `Name`. The same happens if you change `personName.Name`. First it looks up the address in the Variable, goes to that address and changes the field Name. This is why you'll see the Name change in both Variables in this case, and this it what "reference-type" means (A value-type will create a copy, so this won't happen).

But; when you create a new Object, you also create a new Address for the Object to live at - e.g. `4567`. That is what the `new`-keyword does: allocate some memory and create a new object there. This Address is now assigned to `refObj.PersonName`, but *not* `personName` (as the Assignment clearly only happens on the refObj). So `personName` still has the Address `1234` and therefore still points to the old Object.

What `ref` does: When you create the `refObj`, it itself (and all fields) will have a certain Address in Memory. Let's say, `refObj` is at `9900`, and its field `refObj.PersonName` is at `9999`. When you say `personName = refObj.PersonName`, the program looks what Address is stored inside `refObj.PersonName` (1234) and copies it to `personName`, but when you say `ref personName = ref refObj.PersonName`, it takes the Address of the field itself and copies that. So now `personName` has the value `9999` instead. Whenever you access `personName` now, it first looks at Address `9999` and then follows that to whichever Address it contains (1234 or 4567). This is why it will update as well when you change `refObj.PersonName`.

Or, if you're more of the visual type, this is what happens:

```
refObj.PersonName = new Name("Name 1")
```

[image: refObj.PersonName = new Name("Name 1")]

```
personName = refObj.PersonName
```

[image: personName = refObj.PersonName]

```
refObj.PersonName = new Name("Name 2")
```

[image: refObj.PersonName = new Name("Name 2")]

Compare it to what happens when you use the `ref`-keyword:

```
ref personName = ref refObj.PersonName
```

[image: ref personName = ref refObj.PersonName]

```
refObj.PersonName = new Name("Name 2")
```

[image: refObj.PersonName = new Name("Name 2")]

I hope this helps to clear this up a little bit :)

Comment: Thank you. Since Name is a class i.e. already reference type. I assume when we are doing personName = (refObj as PersonData).PersonName; are we not setting the reference instead of value? and since refObj is always pointing to the same memory location, is there anyway that subfields of refObj (Name) always use the same memory location ?

Comment: I've extended the answer to (hopefully) explain more clearly what is going on with references and objects and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is this part of your code:

```
personName = (refObj as PersonData).PersonName;

Console.WriteLine(personName.name);
Console.WriteLine((refObj as PersonData).PersonName.name);


reflection.setValueToObject2();

Console.WriteLine(personName.name);
Console.WriteLine((refObj as PersonData).PersonName.name);
```

here you **assign** the `PersonName` of the first call to the local variable `personName`. As you never assign anything different to `personName` it will allways point to the exact same instance, which is the `Name`-object of your first call. When calling `setValueToObject2` you just create a completely new instance of the `Name`-class which has no relation to the first one at all. Any modification on this instance therefore is not reflected on the first instance and thus also not within `personName`.

Thus `personName` allways reflects the very first `Name`-instance. `(reoObj as PersonData).PersonName` on the other hand points to the actual (second) one.

You can easily fix that by re-assigning `personName`:

```
personName = (refObj as PersonData).PersonName;

Console.WriteLine(personName.name);
Console.WriteLine((refObj as PersonData).PersonName.name);


reflection.setValueToObject2();
personName = (refObj as PersonData).PersonName; // get the new instance

Console.WriteLine(personName.name);
Console.WriteLine((refObj as PersonData).PersonName.name);
```

Comment: I don't want to assign it again. one assignment should always point to the right memory location as the main object refObj is not changing.

Comment: @muhayyuddingillani That means nothing, because a `Name`-object does not know anything about its parent `PersonData`.

Comment: is there any way using reflection that when we are setting the name value to the memory location of the name in the parent object (refObj.PersonName. since this memory location is always there, how can we update the same memory location with new value?

Comment: No, there is no way. As I already said your `Name` does not know anything about the object that uses it. You could even create a `Name`-object without ever having any `PersonData`, meaning you don´t even have any parent object. Unless you dont provide a reference to the parent object within `Name`, the latter class has absolutely no relation to the former.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var refObj = new PersonData(); 
 /* You have only a single Name object 
 * There is a single reference to it
 */

 var reflection = new ReflectionPractice(refObj);

 reflection.setValueToObject1(); 
 /* You have two Name objects
 * Where the name is "" there is no reference anymore 
 * Where the name is "This is first name" there is a single reference
 */

 var personName = (refObj as PersonData).PersonName;      
 /* You have two Name objects
 * Where the name is "" there is no reference anymore 
 * Where the name is "This is first name" there are two references
 */

 reflection.setValueToObject2();
 /* You have three Name objects
 * Where the name is "" there is no reference anymore 
 * Where the name is "This is first name" there is one reference (personName variable)
 * Where the name is "This is second name" there is one reference 
 */
```

That's why your second `Console.WriteLine(personName.name);` print the "this is first name".

Answer (score 0):

Setting values in this way fixed the issue. @CShark

```
public void setValueToObject1()
        {
            FieldInfo fi1 = type.GetField("age");
            FieldInfo fi2 = type.GetField("PersonName");
            fi1.SetValue(localObj, 34);

            TypedReference reference = __makeref(localObj);
            object obj = fi2.GetValueDirect(reference);
            Type localtype = obj.GetType();
            FieldInfo filocal = localtype.GetField("name");
            object o = "first name";
            filocal.SetValueDirect(__makeref(obj),o);
            fi2.SetValue(localObj, obj);


        }

        public void setValueToObject2()
        {
            FieldInfo fi1 = type.GetField("age");
            FieldInfo fi2 = type.GetField("PersonName");

            TypedReference reference = __makeref(localObj);
            object obj = fi2.GetValueDirect(reference);
            Type localtype = obj.GetType();
            FieldInfo filocal = localtype.GetField("name");
            object o = "second name";
            filocal.SetValueDirect(__makeref(obj), o);
            fi2.SetValue(localObj, obj);
        }
```